# VBA Find Multiple Items in a Range and Based Off Other Criteria in Row Copy and Paste Adjacent Cells to Another Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, find, worksheet

I have 3 tabs that come into play for the particular issue that I am trying to automate using VBA.

Form tab:  Users select from a drop down list up to 10 different entities that they need access to (Range A25:A34)

FLS Hiearchy: This tab is a hiearchy of all of the entities within the company beginning with level 1 (highest / parent level) to level 10 (lowest child level).  Range A:D (Column A is the level, B is the entity which will match the various entities selected in dropdown on Form tab, Column C is Entity Description, Column D is the Sec Class which needs to be copied over to sheet 1).

Sheet1:  This tab is for the admin and is to be used to Find the necessary security classes from the FLS Hiearchy tab based upon the entities selected in the form tab. Range A1:J1.  Security classes are to be copied beneath each variable as derived from the Form tab (up to 10 entities, correlating to Column J on Sheet1).

I know that I need to create a loop of some kind to accomplish this.  In a nutshell the VBA script needs to identify the entities (up to 10) from the Form tab, paste them in the Range A1:J1 as necessary, and then go through a loop where it takes the corresponding entities beginning with A1 and find the entities in the FLS Hieararchy tab.  Once it finds each entity in the Hierarchy tab it needs to determine its level (column A) on Hierarchy tab.  If the level is level 6 for example, the VBA script needs to grab the security class for that line where the entity was found and then grab the security class for the entities below it until it finds the next level 6 security class and then it needs to stop there (go up one row to not include the next level 6).  In this example if you find a level 6 and the next entity below it is also a 6 the VBA script only needs to grab the one security class (column d for the first variable).

Below is what I have so far, but I am obviously needing a lot more help to finish.

```
Sub SecurityClasses()
'
' SecurityClasses Macro
' Based off entity selected in Form tab determine the security classes needed for user.
'
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:AZ").ClearContents
Sheets("Form").Activate

Range("A25").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,      SkipBlanks:= _ False, Transpose:=True
```

Comment: You can email me your file and I will take a look at it